# Drying out/refactoring flex/actionscript code

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, refactoring, adobe, mxml

I have something like 10 components that have code that's very similar, except for the target that it's applied to and some other minor differences.

For example, I return xml to `component1` and `component2` that differs in this way:

```
component 1: event.result.names.name
component 2: event.result.phones.phone
```

I then bind these to a `List`, and the name of that list differs by component.

```
component 1: nameslist.dataProvider = 
component 2: phoneslist.dataProvider =
```

How do I create a single method that would accept as parameters just the names/pointers/references to the objects I need worked on. For examples `nameslist` or `phoneslist` as `List` or `.phones.phone` vs. `.names.name` for the structure of the xml returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you can use a function as parameters to your component.

So, you'll have a property like this:

```
public var dataProviderFunction : Function;
```

and the value you'd give it might be something like this:

```
public function getNamesDataProvider(object:XML):xml{ return xml.namesList.dataProvider }
```

Or like this:

```
public function getNamesDataProvider(object:XML):xml{ return xml.phonesList.dataProvider }
```

Take a look at how the List class source code and see how the labelFunction and itemToLabel are implemented.

Comment: Hi Jeffry, Thanks for the answer. Is this code supposed to be in the main application file? Sorry, I'm still a little confused. Haven't wrapped my head totally around your answer.

Comment: The public var would go in your component. The function that you're using as an argument would most likely go in the component's parent.  If you provided a full sample, it would be easier to point and say "put it here".